# Select most recent status for each ID and department code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to get the most recent status for each dept_code that a CL_ID has. So the desired output would be this:

[image]

I have tried the following but this give me just the most recent status for each client and not each of their dept_codes.

```
SELECT *
FROM [CIMSHR6_MERGED].[dbo].[C3CLSTAT] C
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT CLIENT_NUMBER, MAX(STATUS_DATE) AS SDATE
    FROM [CIMSHR6_MERGED].[dbo].[C3CLSTAT]
    GROUP BY CLIENT_NUMBER) X
ON X.CLIENT_NUMBER = C.CLIENT_NUMBER
AND X.SDATE = C.STATUS_DATE
ORDER BY C.CLIENT_NUMBER
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It's probably SQL Server with the square brackets and `dbo` in there.  Maybe it could be Access, but I'd be surprised by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convenient method that works in SQL Server is:

```
select top (1) cl.*
from [CIMSHR6_MERGED].[dbo].[C3CLSTAT] cl
order by row_number() over (partition by cl_id, dept_code order by status_date desc);
```

A method that is efficient with the right indexes in almost any database is:

```
select cl.*
from [CIMSHR6_MERGED].[dbo].[C3CLSTAT] cl
where cl.status_date = (select max(cl2.status_date)
                        from [CIMSHR6_MERGED].[dbo].[C3CLSTAT] cl2
                        where cl2.cl_id = cl.cl_id and cl2.dept_code = cl.dept_code
                       );
```

The right index is on `(cl_id, dept_code, status_date)`.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would also use `ROW_NUMBER`, but with a subquery:

```
SELECT CL_ID, Status_date, Status, Dept_code
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CL_ID, Dept_code ORDER BY Status_date DESC) rn
    FROM CIMSHR6_MERGED].[dbo].[C3CLSTAT]
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Firstly group everything on Dept_Code,CL_ID and assign rank for each row with in the group in descending order.
2) Select all the rows with rnk=1 which would display your desired result. 

    SELECT Z.CL_ID,
           Z.Status_Date,
           Z.Status,
           Z.Dept_Code
      FROM 
         (
             SELECT *,
                    RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY Dept_Code,CL_ID, ORDER BY Status_Date DESC ) AS rnk
               FROM [CIMSHR6_MERGED].[dbo].[C3CLSTAT]
          ) Z
       WHERE Z.rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work for almost all databases

```
select * from c3clstat c
where exists
(select 1 from c3clstat c1
  where c1.cl_id=c.cl_id
  and c1.dept_code=c.dept_code
group by cl_id,dept_code
having c.status_date=max(c1.status_date)
)
```